# Using collect closure method to populate a HashMap in groovy

Tags: groovy, arraylist, hashmap, closures, collect

I am trying to populate a Map from an List. Here's what I am doing.

```
itemNoList = [1,2,3,4]
bookMap = [:]
bookMap = itemNoList.collect{ [ (it) : it+1 ] }
```

When I do this, the bookMap changes to ArrayList type and now has a List of HashMap.

`bookMap` is now `[{1=2}, {2=3}, {3=4}, {4=5}]`, i.e a List of Maps.

How would I be able to get a HashMap from the ArrayList using `collect` method? It would be easy to solve this by using an `each` instead `collect`, but I'm just curious whether it could be solved using `collect`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're in luck! The [`collectEntries`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) method handles works just like `collect` but for a Map!

```
groovy:000> itemNoList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
===> [1, 2, 3, 4]
groovy:000> itemNoList.collectEntries { [(it): it+1] }
===> {1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5}
```

Comment: Awesome!, this is exactly what I wanted!